# Numpy insert strings into an array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create a numpy array of strings. Initially I start with an empty array, which I then fill up with strings as they are generated in a for-loop.

```
strings = np.empty(size, np.unicode_)

for i in range (size):
    strings[i] = ("Name" + str(i))
```

However, it seems like it only takes the first letter of the string and inserts that one:

```
output: ['N' 'N' 'N' 'N' 'N' 'N' 'N' 'N' 'N' 'N']
```

What am I doing wrong and how should I correctly do this?

Comment: Why are you using numpy for this in the first place?

Comment: Anyway, the problem is that only enough memory is allocated for the first character. Look at `strings.dtype`; your strings thus get truncated at each index

Comment: I need to prepare my data in such a way that I can use `scipy.io` to create a `.mat`file from it. Converting everything into numpy arrays and then adding them to a dictionary is how the documentation describes it, so I'm trying to replicate that.

Comment: In that case, I suggest that you perform this operation using only a list and then just call `np.array()` on the end result to do the conversion then. Especially since your strings might grow to an arbitrary length; you can then allow numpy to figure out the correct dtype on the final conversion

Comment: `np.unicode_ `
does not allow you more characters per position

Comment: What would be the correct dtype?

Comment: The one that can accommodate the longest string. Which numpy would work out for you if you follow my suggestion to do this particular operation with a _list_ and then convert afterwards

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need [`np.array`](http://dtype%20:%20data-type,%20optional%20The%20desired%20data-type%20for%20the%20array.%20If%20not%20given,%20then%20the%20type%20will%20be%20determined%20as%20the%20minimum%20type%20required%20to%20hold%20the%20objects%20in%20the%20sequence.%20This%20argument%20can%20only%20be%20used%20to%20%E2%80%98upcast%E2%80%99%20the%20array.%20For%20downcasting,%20use%20the%20.astype(t)%20method.) with list comprehension.

> dtype : data-type, optional
>   The desired data-type for the array. If not given, then the type will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence. This argument can only be used to ‘upcast’ the array. For downcasting, use the .astype(t) method.

```
size = 11
np.array([f'Name{i}' for i in range(size)])
#np.array(['Name{}'.format(i) for i in range(size)])

#array(['Name0', 'Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6',
#       'Name7', 'Name8', 'Name9', 'Name10'], dtype='<U6')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.chararray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.html) and set the maximal itemsize. The itemsize can then be computed by using the 10th log. Here a sample:

```
import math
size = 11

item_maxsize = 4 + math.ceil(math.log10(size)) 
strings = np.chararray(size, itemsize = item_maxsize, unicode = True)

for i in range (size):
    strings[i] = ("Name" + str(i))
```

Result:

```
chararray(['Name0', 'Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6',
           'Name7', 'Name8', 'Name9', 'Name10'], dtype='<U6')
```

Comment: doesn't `np.empty(size, dtype="<U6")` work as well ?

Comment: @AxeonThra It does. But the problem it will only work if size<100. For size 101, you will nead `<U7`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your array dtype to `"S_N"` with `N` being the size of your string (largest string you intend to insert). like this:

```
strings = np.empty(size, "S10")

for i in range (size):
    strings[i] = ("Name" + str(i))
```

output:

```
[b'Name0' b'Name1' b'Name2' b'Name3' b'Name4' b'Name5' b'Name6' b'Name7'
 b'Name8' b'Name9']
```